# What is the difference between playTogether(x,y) and play(x).with(y)?

Tags: android, android-animation

After testing, both `playTogether()` and the combination of `play()` followed by `with()` result in two animations playing at the same time. Android docs don't help either:

> playTogether added in API level 11 public void playTogether
>   (Collection items) Sets up this AnimatorSet to play all of
>   the supplied animations at the same time.

And

> For example, calling play(a1).with(a2) sets up the AnimatorSet to play
>   a1 and a2 at the same time,

Is there a difference between them? Are there cases where one is required while the other isn't?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/animation/AnimatorSet.java#129

Comment: @pskink showed you a link to the `playTogether` source where it shows that `playTogether` is just doing `with` for every animation in collection. In other words, it is just a shortcut to write `playTogether(animationList)` instead of `play(a1).with(a2).with(a3).with(a4).with(a5).with(a6).with(a7).with(a8)`